# Nginx config as image server , but get 403 forbidden error

Tags: nginx-config

I tried to configure nginx as image server as below

create myapp.conf and put it at /etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {

    listen 80;

    listen [::]:80; 

     #here you could also use subdomain

    server_name image.mydomain.com ;

    #here you could also use context,e.g. location /<context>

    location / {

      root /myapp/imageServer/;

      autoindex on;

    }

}
```

The file exists at /myapp/imageServer/card/3cdad37c5a394567b53283321f6af9e9.png

But when i browse this file via https://image.mydomain.com/card/3cdad37c5a394567b53283321f6af9e9.png. I got 403 forbidden from nginx. There is any mistake of my nginx config?

Comment: Pretty sure you need `allow all;` inside the location block.

Answer (score 1):

i found the reason

go to /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

edit line as below

```
#user www-data;
user root;
```